# Batch if statements not working

Tags: batch-file

The following code is not working. Whatever I input just returns an error, and then goes back to `Retry`.

```
@echo off

:maths
set /p Mathsa="first number? "
echo your first number is %Mathsa%

:retry

set /p Mathso="operator?(+-*/) "
if "%Mathso%" ==* GOTO run
if "%Mathso%" ==/ GOTO run
if "%Mathso%" ==+ GOTO run
if "%Mathso%" ==- GOTO run
echo Error, wrong operator. & goto retry

:run
set /p Mathsb="Second Number? "
set /a Mathsans=%Mathsa%%Mathsp%%Mathsb%
echo %Mathsans%
pause
```

I have absolutely no idea why it's doing this. It's for a school project and any help you can give would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the quotes around your `Mathso` variable. Change them all to use quotes around *both* sides of the equality, such as with:

```
if "%Mathso%" == "+" GOTO run
```

and they should work better.

The reason for this is that `cmd` is not quite the same as UNIXy shells. The quotes are preserved on the left hand of the equality so that what you end up with is:

```
if "+" == + then ...
```

and `"+"` is *not* equal to `+`.

By putting quotes on both sides, it becomes:

```
if "+" == "+" then ...
```

which *is* true.

---

And, as Aacini points out in the comment, your calculation `set` uses the wrong variable for the operator. You should change:

```
set /a Mathsans=%Mathsa%%Mathsp%%Mathsb%
```

into:

```
set /a Mathsans=%Mathsa%%Mathso%%Mathsb%
                              ^
                              |
                              see here
```

Comment: And also in this command: `set /a Mathsans=%Mathsa%%Mathsp%%Mathsb%
` the intermediate variable must be `%MathsO%` instead `%MathsP%`...